# Limit a user logged in by ssh to read only?

Tags: bash, ssh, read-only

I am using backuppc to backup some hosts - but I want to limit the backuppc's rsync command on that hosts to "read only".

One option would be to get the rsync command and limit the backuppcs ssh key to this command.

But is there any option to - for example - limit the shell for the ssh key to read only operations? For example by enforcing apparmor/selinux rules or so?

Answer (score 2):

Write a PAM module that hooks into `pam_sm_open_session` and does the rough equivalent of `mount -o rbind,ro / /` in a separate mount namespace created using unshare(). Have only /etc/pam.d/ssh call this module. (Similar to systemd's ProtectSystem= for services.)

AppArmor may work; there is probably an existing PAM session module to attach an AppArmor profile by name. Again, set up pam.d/ssh to call that module, possibly combined with pam_succeed_if.so to skip the module for unconfined users.

Don't give the backup client root privileges; instead give it only the `cap_dac_read_search` privilege alone. (Again, by using a PAM session module to twiddle process "ambient capabilities" via prctl() or libcap.) This will allow the client to bypass file permissions like root can, but *only* for reading – not writing.

Comment: Wow. This may really be two elegant solutions. Even the first one - with such bind mounts I would be able to only disclose the data that the backup prozess should see...

Thank you for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

By default, users can only write into their home directory
(which they own), any location that has 777 access
(`/run/shm`, `/tmp`, and a few other places), and any other location
that they have user ownership.

If you create a user account that only owns its home folder,
it will naturally have only read-access to the rest of the system
(besides the above mentioned exceptions).

Comment: The external script will have to use the root user. It has to read _all_ the files.

Comment: You could also use chroot to only include what you like in what that user thinks is the entire system.

Comment: Great idea! I'll implement a mixture with @user1686 solution